# Question on Netstat output "app --node-in" & other

Tags: process, background-process, netstat

While doing "netstat -p", I got result out of which, I am unable to understand below output:-

```
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  3889891  23976/app --node-in  
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  33223    1759/evolution-sour
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  34083    1776/goa-daemon
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  33035    1673/at-spi2-regist
unix  2  [ ]  DGRAM              225771   23687/obexd
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  32032    1767/gvfs-afc-volum
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  34783    1990/evolution-cale
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  33175    1749/gnome-shell-ca
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  36886    2012/evolution-addr
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  32297    1990/evolution-cale
unix  3  [ ]  STREAM  CONNECTED  32298    2003/evolution-addr
```

`app --node-in` was visible multiple times, not sure, what process is that

What programs or apps are responsible for above process, and is `gnome-shell-ca` thing?, I though it is only `gnome-shell` exists.

Comment: This sounds like `app` was listening on multiple UNIX sockets; try using `netstat -ap` or lsof next time to see which socket files it has open. Also, your package manager should have a facility to identify which package owns a file. Use `which app` to find the path, and do some research (readas: googling) on your package manager to find out which package owns it.

Comment: `which app` returns blank and `lsof` actually tells the path to be:- `/snap/vscode/77/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar...`